# ES6 setInterval(() => foo(), 1000 vs setInterval(foo, 1000)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, setinterval, arrow-functions

I'm working on learning React and I'm following this tutorial
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html and in it an interval is set inside a react component class and the syntax used is `setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000)` where tick is a method in the `Clock` component. My question is this: So this arrow function simply calls `this.tick()` when its called, and `setInterval` will call it, so what is the difference between just passing in `this.tick` without wrapping it in an arrow function like so `setInterval(this.tick, 1000)`? I thought there would be no difference, but removing the wrap in an arrow function and the clock doesn't work. Whats going on? Here is a link to a codepen demonstrating the issue https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aKNJGd?editors=0011 (line 12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds related to how [`this` works in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). With the arrow function, you get `this` from the React component via closure scope. Without the arrow function, the `this.tick` that gets called has a different (or no) `this`.

Add this in your constructor and it will work without the arrow function.

`this.tick = this.tick.bind(this)`